# Task.apply vs. Task.now wrt Function Totality

Tags: scala, scalaz

Given:

```
$cat build.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.2.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-concurrent" % "7.2.5"
```

### REPL

```
scala> import scalaz.concurrent.Task
import scalaz.concurrent.Task

scala> def f(num: BigDecimal, denom: BigDecimal): Task[BigDecimal] = 
           Task { num / denom }
f: (num: BigDecimal, denom: BigDecimal)scalaz.concurrent.Task[BigDecimal]

scala> def g(num: BigDecimal, denom: BigDecimal): Task[BigDecimal] = 
      Task.now { num / denom }
g: (num: BigDecimal, denom: BigDecimal)scalaz.concurrent.Task[BigDecimal]
```

I then call `f` and `g` with a `0` value for `denom`:

```
scala> f(1, 0)
res0: scalaz.concurrent.Task[BigDecimal] = scalaz.concurrent.Task@208b1305

scala> g(1, 0)
java.lang.ArithmeticException: Division by zero
  at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:1742)
  at scala.math.BigDecimal.$div(BigDecimal.scala:571)
  at .g(<console>:12)
  ... 42 elided
```

Is it fair to say that `f` is a total function, whereas `g` is partial?

Comment: Not too sure about the definitions, but appending `unsafePerformSync` to both should give you the same result.

Comment: `"Not too sure about the definitions"` - could you please say more, @Reactormonk? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Function totality. `Task.now` evaluates the argument, `Task.apply` doesn't.

Comment: Care to post that as an answer, @Reactormonk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Task.now` evaluates its argument, `Task.apply` doesn't. So you're not even testing your assumption in the second case, that's why you don't see an exception. Run them via `unsafePerformSync` to run the code inside the `Task` constructed with `apply`.